# Parse and pass data before the component is loaded in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am trying to learn Angular and facing a problem. In my home component I need to parse this data (from my local storage) and pass to the home page.
The problem is, upon first try this data is null and the subsequent tries, I'm guessing i'm getting the previous data.

Here the code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() data;
    // @Input() data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('videos')); // 
    <-- Try this
    constructor(private videosService: VideosService, private 
      authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {
      // let datos = localStorage.getItem('videos'); // <-- Try this
      // this.data = JSON.parse(datos); // <-- Try this
    }
    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(localStorage);
      // let data = localStorage.getItem('videos'); // <-- Try this
      // let datos = localStorage.getItem('videos'); // <-- Try this
      //  this.data = JSON.parse(datos); // <-- Try this
      console.log(this.data);
    }
```

The code in comments is what I have tried.

Comment: To clarify your question, you are saving some data in localstorage, but somehow the data is null inside HomeComponent when calling localStorage.getItem('videos')?

Comment: Exactly. The data into localstorage.getItem('videos') is already saved before the home component is called. I need to pass this data into @Input data so I can use it in the home page.
Sorry if I'm not clear, I'm new at this too.

Comment: Can you show the html code for HomeComponent?

Comment: I think you're using the Input decorator wrong. It's used to pass data from parent component into child component.

Comment: What exactly is localStorage? Is that another Angular Component? If so, your understanding of @Input decorator could be wrong. I'm assuming you had gone through https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. May be you should create a plunker with your code, so its easier to help.